# Importing JSON objects to Google Sheets as integers

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I'm importing values from different APIs using a script on Google Sheets.

On each cell, I have the function below:

```
=ImportJSON("https://apiservice.com/api/v1.1/public", "/result/Last", "noHeaders")
```

It works fine, but when I try to obtain the highest value in a range of these cells using the **=MAX()** function I just get "0" as result.

My guess is Sheets isn't recognizing it as an integer. Is there any workaround for this?

This is the scrip I'm using: https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258

Answer (score 0):

So simple I'm embarassed.

I just multiplied it by 1 (***1**) at the end of the function and voila! It works!

```
=ImportJSON("https://apiservice.com/api/v1.1/public", "/result/Last", "noHeaders")*1
```